# How is use local::lib different from use lib?

Tags: perl, locallib

I don't understand what [`use local::lib`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm) does that regular [`use lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) doesn't. Could someone explain it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`local::lib`

1. Defaults to `~/perl5` if you don't specify a directory (while `use lib;` is a no-op).
2. Resolves relative paths to absolute paths before adding them to `@INC`.  (`lib` just adds the relative path as-is.)
3. Expands `~` and `~user` in the directory name.
4. Appends `/lib/perl5` to the directory you specify. (So `use local::lib '/foo';` is somewhat equivalent to `use lib '/foo/lib/perl5';`.)
5. Prepends `DIR/bin` to your PATH, so you can use scripts installed by local modules.

Answer (score 6):

`use lib` adds a directory to your module search path (`@INC`).  It has no effect on anything outside of the program or module which contains the `use lib` directive.

`local::lib` is intended to be used to enable a private module installation directory and, if you configure your shell environment in the way that it recommends, this private directory will be used for all Perl module installations (whether via CPAN or manual `make install`) and modules installed there will be made available to all Perl programs/modules run from within your `local::lib`-aware shell environment.

Answer (score 5):

Regular `use lib foo` is almost as simple as:

```
BEGIN { unshift(@INC, foo) }
```

Whereas `use local::lib` sets many other Perl environment variables to make sure you can install modules locally, see the source.